# Dynamic rollover buttons in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have question mark help links on my page. Each one is located inside a div with identical class names, and an attribute. The attribute is used to select the appropriate text from my database. The code below grabs the question mark image, along with its appropriate text:

```
echo "<div class=helptab att=runcampaign>".$help->GetHelpTab()."</div>";
```

The php code for this function is here:

```
public function GetHelpTab() {
$helptab = "<div id=helptabs><img src=../images/help_tab.jpg>";
$helptab .= "<div id=helpwindow></div></div>";
return $helptab;

}
```

My page contains multiple helptab divs. When each is rolled over, it displays the appropriate text. The text window (helpwindow) that holds the text is also shown. But the problem is the window is always located in the same spot. I need it to display with the appropriate question mark box. Here is my jquery to make that happen:

```
$('.helptab').mouseenter(function() {

var classname = $(this).attr('att');
ShowText(classname);

});


function ShowText(classname) {

$.post('../lib/helptabtext.php', {
classname: classname,

}, function(data) {

if(data) {
    $('#helpwindow').show();
    $('#helpwindow').html(data);
}

}, 'text');

}
```

Comment: What if id becomes class instead? The question marks are class tags, each with the same class name. If I do the same for helpwindow, I still get the undesired result.

Comment: Yes, using classes would be the better approach. I haven't tried to duplicate your problem, but if you could create a jsFiddle that would be helpful.